# @media only screen and (max-device-width : 480px) didn't work

Tags: html, css

I already put
< meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> in the head. But the  @media only screen and (max-device-width : 480px) will only work for 1 second and then changed to 720px and 1333.41px CSS.

I'm trying to make the bg picture to change for 480px and 720px, the 720px and 1333.41px works well, only 480 not. What to do?

what 480px looks like right now

[image: what 480px looks like rn]

what the background supposed to look like

[image: what the background supposed to look like]

Here's my style tag

```css
<style>
    body{
        /* background-image:url(Background1.png); */
        background-image:url(Background-013.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
    }
    .style {
        max-width: 500px;
        margin: auto;
        color: Black;
        font-family: Roboto-Regular;
        padding: 30px;
        background-color:rgba(255, 255,255, 0.4);
        border-radius: 15px;
        margin-top: 300px;
    }
    .style2 {
        max-width: 500px;
        margin: auto;
        color: Black;
        font-family: Roboto-Regular;
        padding: 30px;
        background-color:rgba(255, 255,255, 0.4);
        border-radius: 15px;

    }
    .form-control{
        background-color:rgba(255, 255,255, 0); 
        color: white;
    }
    .form-label{
        color: white;
    }
    .dropdown{
        text-align:left;
    }
    .langkah {
        text-align: left;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    #email, #nama,#lomba,#idLine,#bukti{
    border-radius: 0;
    /* border-color: white; */
    } 
    input[type=file]::file-selector-button{
        background-color: #DA4327;
        color: white;
    }
    #submit{
        background-color: #DA4327;
        border-radius: 0;
        border-color: #DA4327;
    }
    #klikLangkah {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .judul{
        height: 300px;
        width: auto;
        position: absolute;
        margin: auto;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
 
    @media only screen and (max-device-width : 480px){ 
        .judul{
        content: url(3.png) !important;
        height: 50%;
        position: absolute;
        max-width:480px;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        left: 0;
        } 
        body{
        background-image:url(Bg phone.png) !important;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
        }
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width:1333.41px) { 
        .judul{
            content: url(3.png) !important;
            top: 0;
            width:auto;
            height:50%;
            right: 50px;
            margin: auto;
            position: absolute;
        } 
    }
   
    @media only screen and (max-width:720px){ 
        .judul{
            content: url(3.png) !important;
            width:auto;
            height: 50%;
            position: absolute;
            max-width:720px;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            left: 0;
        } 

        body{
        background-image:url(Background-02720.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
        }
    }
  </style>
```

```html
 <div class="container">
    <img class="judul" src="Ayuk Daftar2.png">
</div>
    
  <!--form-->
    <form class="style" method="POST" action="pendaftaran.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="mb-3 ">
                <select class="dropdown form-control" name="lomba" id ="lomba" style="background-color: #F7B21A;color: white;"> 
                    <option style="text-align:center; color: white;">Pilih lomba mu di sini!</option>
                    <?php
                        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
                        {
                    ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>"><?php echo $row['lomba'];?></option>
                    <?php
                    }?>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="form-label">Nama</label>
            <?php
            if(isset($_SESSION['name'])){
                $nama = $_SESSION['name'];
            }
            else{
                $nama = "";
            }
            ?>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nama" id="nama" value ="<?php echo $nama?>" >
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <?php
            if(isset($_SESSION['mail'])){
                $e_mail = $_SESSION['mail'];
            }
            else{
                $e_mail = "";
            }
            ?>
            <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="form-label">Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" value ="<?php echo $e_mail?>" >
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <?php
            if(isset($_SESSION['line'])){
                $lineID = $_SESSION['line'];
            }
            else{
                $lineID = "";
            }
            ?>
            <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="form-label">ID Line</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="idLine" id="idLine" value ="<?php echo $lineID?>" >
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="formFile" class="form-label">Bukti pembayaran (harus 1)</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="bukti" type="file" id="bukti">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" style="margin-right: 100px">Submit</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn" id="klikLangkah" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#langkah" style="color: white;">*klik untuk langkah-langkah <br> &nbsp; melakukan pendaftaran</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Please see [ask]. CSS doesn't really help without some HTML. Also, don't write in text-speak. Use real words, please.

Comment: Please provide the HTML you use with this CSS.

Comment: provided it, i don't really know what to include, so i put the form and header text image inside

Comment: Any @media selector with '(min/max)-device-(ratio/width/height)' is deprecated. Are you sure your browser still supports those selectors??

Comment: it should be? i use chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px){ 
    .judul {
        content: url(3.png) !important;
        height: 50%;
        position: absolute;
        max-width:480px;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        left: 0;
    } 

    body {
        background-image:url(Bg phone.png) !important;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
    }
}
```

Comment: it's still the same

Comment: And if you inspect the page, what does the DOM show?

Comment: <div class="container">
        <img class="judul" src="Ayuk Daftar2.png">
    </div> this for title image, and nothing for bg

Comment: Make your code work in codepen.io, if you share a link i can have a look at it working live.

Comment: https://codepen.io/bubleygum/pen/vYWWRrx

Comment: Okay i've tested it in the codepen, seems to me that it is working. i will add a picture below.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242072/discussion-between-menno-spijker-and-bubleygum).

Answer (score 0):

change `max-device-width` to `max-width`

Comment: it's still the same